# What is the difference between a 'Call Behavior' and 'Call Operation' action in fUML?

Tags: uml

What is the difference between a 'Call Behavior' and 'Call Operation' action in foundational UML (fUML)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplified, CallBehavior calls directly a Behavior and the CallOperation invokes specifically a method's Operation.

Behavior can be seen as any other behavior diagram, like activity, sequence, etc. 
Operation is much more concrete.

Extract from UML spec:

[image]

If you want more formal explanation, please read about the following concepts in the UML spec: Behavior, BehavioralFeature, Operation and finally both mentiones Actions.